# .htaccess imagenes no funcina

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy configurando mi htaccess y la url funciona correctamente, también he conseguido arreglar el js pero las imágenes no consigo que funcionen.
Este es mi .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ blog.php?id=$1&lang=$2
```

el directorio de las imágenes es blog/images/subcarpeta/imagen dentro del php estan 
images/subcarpeta/$image

pero no se que regla poner para que funcinen.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado la solución.

Al comprobar si existe la imagen, lo dejamos

```
 $imagen="images/subcarpeta/".$image;
```

Cuando lo dibujamos en el

Hay que añadir la carpeta

```
 <img src="blog/".$imagen" ...>
```